# Writing a list based on another list on Prolog

Tags: prolog

So, in this prolog program i have this "fruit database", this "person database" and a "ate database"...

```
%fruit(FId, Name,   Type, Price).

fruit(1, 'apple'            , sweet  , 5).
fruit(2, 'greenApple'  , bitter , 5).
fruit(3, 'grape'            , sweet  , 10).
fruit(4, 'peach'            , sweet  , 20).
fruit(5, 'orange'           , citric , 5).
fruit(6, 'tangerine'        , citric , 7).
fruit(7, 'banana'           , sweet  , 3).
fruit(8, 'lemon'            , citric , 6).
fruit(9, 'bitterMelons', citric , 12).
fruit(10,'grapefruit'       , citric , 8).

%.          (don't mind these dots, they're meant for a better visual experience)


%person(PId, P).

person(1, 'ana').
person(2, 'john').

%.

%ate(PId, FId).

ate(1, [1, 2, 3, 4]).
ate(2, [1, 3, 5, 8]).
```

I also have this rule so i can query what fruits, types of fruits or price of the fruit that someone ate.

```
person_ate(P, F, T, M) :-
   person(PId, P),
   ate(PId, FruitIds),
   member(FId, FruitIds),
   fruit(FId, F, T, M).
%.
person_ate_fruits(P,F, _, _) :-
    findall(F,person_ate(P,F, _, _),F).
%.
person_ate_types(P, _,T, _) :-
    findall(T,person_ate(P, _,T, _),T).
%.
person_ate_prices(P, _, _,M) :-
    findall(M,person_ate(P, _, _,M),M).
```

I also have these 3 rules that tell me wether a fruit is cheap or expensive or if it is "middle priced".

```
cheap_fruit(FId, F, T, M)                   :- fruit(FId, F, T, M), M =< 6.
expensive_fruit(FId, F, T, M)               :- fruit(FId, F, T, M), M > 15.
middleprice_fruit(FId, F, T, M)             :- fruit(FId, F, T, M), M > 6, M =< 12.
```

So, my goal is to recommend fruits based on the type of fruit or price that someone ate.

Eg: As we see, when i query

```
person_ate_fruits('ana',F, _, _).
```

i can see that Ana ate
`F = [apple, greenApple, grape, peach]`

and querying

```
person_ate_types('ana', _,T, _).
```

and the types of fruits she ate
`T = [sweet, bitter, sweet, sweet]`

Ok, beautiful, now there's bad part

```
recomend(P, R) :-
    person_ate(P, F, T, M),
    TcounterBitter is 0, %supposed to be a Type Counter for the Bitter Type and so are the others.
    TcounterSweet is 0,
    TcounterCitric is 0,
    (T = sweet -> TcounterBitter is +1 ; ), %supposed to everytime i call person_ate_types('ana', _,T, _). count how many Bitter fruits the person ate and so are the others.
    (T = sweet -> TcounterSweet is +1 ; ),
    (T = sweet -> TcounterCitric is +1 ; ).
%.
(TcounterBitter => 3  -> recomend_fruits(P, _,T, _) ; ). %supposed to when one of the counters gets 3 or more (if one person ate more the 3 bitters, sweet or citric fruits), recommend fruits.
(TcounterSweet => 3  -> recomend_fruits(P, _,T, _) ; ).
(TcounterCitric => 3  -> recomend_fruits(P, _,T, _) ; ).
%.
recomend_fruits(P, Fruit) :-
    person_ate(P, F, T, M),
    fruit(FId, Fruit, T, M),
    findall(Fruit,fruits(P,Fruit, _, _), Fruit /= person_ate_fruits(F)). %supposed to go through the fruit list and recommend fruits that are on the Type of fruits most ate and that the person didn't ate yet.
```

I'm sorry for my bad english, it isn't my native language, i hope it's 'understandable'.

Comment: *now there's bad part*.... so what happened? Error message? Wrong results? I see a few syntax errors, like `... ; )` and an invalid operator `=>`. And what does `Fruit /= person_ate_fruits(F)` mean?

Comment: Yes, there are many sintax errors, it seems that my logic is just plain wrong.  findall(Fruit,fruits(P,Fruit, _, _), Fruit /= person_ate_fruits(F)). was meant to find all fruits, get the fruit list and show me every fruit that the person hasn't eat

Comment: `/=` is not a valid Prolog operator. Also, see the documentation for [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) for proper usage. The 3rd argument is unified with the results, which is a list of all the results that satisfy the goal (2nd argument).